# Shrink width of CSS grid cell to make room for sidebar

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a two-column grid layout and I'm struggling to achieve the wanted effect. Block A is fixed size. Block B is fixed width, but its height can vary based on the content. And block C is fixed height. This is how it currently looks as B expands:

```
A A B
A A B
C C C

 -->

A A B
A A B
    B
C C C
```

However, what I'd like to achieve is that as soon as B becomes taller than A, C should also shrink to the width of A so that B can grow freely.

```
A A B
A A B
C C C

 -->

A A B
A A B
C C B
```

Is this possible to achieve with CSS grid/flexbox/a combination of the two? I have full control of both the markup and CSS, so I can change them as needed.

Comment: Look into `grid-auto-flow: dense`.

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible without Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is 100% what you want, but it might work. This was done using css grid and position:relative to overlap "C".
Take a look at the following code:

```css
.container{
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
 grid-template-rows: 20vh 20vh 20vh;
 grid-column-gap: 20px;
 grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

.grid-item:nth-of-type(1){
 grid-column: 1/3;
 grid-row: 1/3;
 background: green;
}

.grid-item:nth-of-type(2){
 grid-column: 3;
 grid-row: 1/-1;
 background: pink;
 position: relative;
 height: calc(60vh + 40px);
}

.grid-item:nth-of-type(3){
 grid-column: 1/-1;
 grid-row: 3;
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid-item">A</div>
  <div class="grid-item">B</div>
  <div class="grid-item">C</div>
 </div>
```